# Java Read a html file and save its content to a excel file

Tags: java, html, excel

Html file code sample :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>REPORT</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<TITLE>REPORT</TITLE><PRE><H2>################ REPORT ###################</H2><H3>Setup</H3>   Item1                   1120                                       <br>   Item2                  Copy free                                    <br>   Item3                   8/3/2017  5:44:51 AM                     <br>   Item4                 <Press OK>                          <br>
```

The information I need to read are the lines with `<br>`. The goal is to save these information to a excel file like below

[image]

I currently use BufferedReader to read the html file, but I dont know how to separate the line contains the field and value. I was trying to use hashmap to save its field name and value, but I cant get the value in a correct way. I also tried Jsoup to get rid of the HTML tag, but it gives me more complexity to read the line since the html file

```
private final String[] modStrings = new String[]{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"};

public void readHtmlFile() throws IOException {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\file.html");
         // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        String[] tempContent = {};
        ArrayList content = new ArrayList();
        HashMap modMap = new HashMap<>();
        while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            tempContent = line.split("<br>");
            for(int i = 0; i < tempContent.length; i++){
                for (String sub:modStrings){
                    if(tempContent[i].contains(sub)){
                        String value = "TODO HERE";  // TODO
                        content.add(sub);
                        modMap.put(sub, value);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
//        String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
        for(int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(content.get(i));
            System.out.println(modMap);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions or ideas will be a lot of help.

Comment: With your html structure above, using the `split("<br")` is not give you what you want. You should using `split` with `space` to get the `Item` and value

Comment: you can use String[] keyVal = s.trim().split(" +"); value = keyVal[1]; key = keyVal[0);

Comment: @TuyenNguyen, I can't use split(" ") since sometime the value contains a space also, if I split with space it will also split the value I want. 
(For example, copy free and 8/3/2017  5:44:51 AM)

Comment: @MinwuYu that's ok. Another solution: Your html is simple only item and value, you can split your string into 2 part by using `split(" ", 2)` => first part is item, remove the `<br>` in 2nd part and using `trim` function to get the value

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Can you provide a code sample base on my current code and post as a Answer? It may give me clear view to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for you is simple, just using the util function of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, based on your html content to use the suitable method to get the content you want. For example here I am using [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), [`split(String regex, int limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)),`trim`or`subString`... to do a simple trick

Sample code for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] modStrings = new String[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("html.html");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        String[] tempContent = {};
        ArrayList content = new ArrayList();
        HashMap<String, String> modMap = new HashMap<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("<br>")) {
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf("Item1"));
            tempContent = line.split("<br>");
            for (String item : tempContent) {
                if (item.contains("Item")) {
                    String[] itemArr = item.trim().split(" ", 2);
                    String itemName = itemArr[0].trim();
                    String value = itemArr[1].trim();
                    modMap.put(itemName, value);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        for(String key : modMap.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + ":" + modMap.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this code can't work correctly. I updated my html file to its original format. The old html sample is aiming to provide a better vision, but I think it made ppl misunderstand the question, as well as in your case here. the if condition cant work correctly. As well as the statements inside the if condition..

Comment: Answers that consist of code but no explanation are not generally welcomed on Stack Overflow.  Can you explain why you think this code will meet OP's requirement?

Comment: @MinwuYu I have updated the code for your new html format. Previous code is not run because you have change the html code. You should know that you want to get help about reading the content then you must post the content exactly

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have provided the idea in the post's comment, but the OP don't know how to do it and ask me to give a sample code so that I did not explain here

Comment: @TuyenNguyen, thank you for all the updated codes and your explanation. I now have the code works correctly.